# What is the formal classification of d3.js? Framework? Library? Package?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, package, d3.js

I've been using d3.js but have no idea how it fits into the grand scope of software development.

- It uses JavaScript
- It sits ontop of the DOM
- Has a very interesting (at times, perhaps even declarative) style of coding
- It can use SVG, but doesn't have to

What is its formal classification?

Can it really be a framework? Does it actually provide a skeleton/Inversion of Control? Or is it just basically a library? Or is it a package, etc?

Answer (score 2):

> *"D3.js is a **JavaScript library** for manipulating documents […]"*

Source: http://d3js.org

Comment: Thanks! But this is just the 'advertising' on the front page of d3's site. Can you back up its classification as a library using systems theory / formal classifications? I think this is quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a data-processing/geometry library combined with DOM manipulation framework. 
D3 has a ton useful generic functions that can be used for anything data related.
But it also includes a framework for manipulating the DOM specifically.

There is very clear inversion of control when using the d3 DOM framework. For instance the attr() method accepts 2 arguments, a string and a function, and d3 executes the function and assigns it's return value to the DOM element as the property specified in the string..

So, formally, I'd classify d3 as a framebrary or a libwork... ?? maybe? Or if that's still too informal then whatever, we're programmers, we make up meanings for all of these words anyways.